# UWP - Shutting down device using ShutdownManager

Tags: c#, uwp, shutdown

**System characteristics**

Windows 10 Pro 1903

**Description**

I have an UWP application running in kiosk mode on a Windows 10 Pro tablet. I want the app to shutdown my device when the application flow is ended. I'm trying to reach it by using

`ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown(ShutdownKind.Shutdown, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));`

As the documentation says I added the **iot capability** in the manifest of my application and the iot field in the **IgnorableNamespace** field.
The problem is that this code only close my application and not shut down the device.

As the ShutdownManager documentation reports:

> **ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown** Shuts down a device that runs in *fixed-purpose mode*, and optionally restarts the device after the specified number of seconds.

Could the *fixed-purpose mode* be the problem?
Is there any other way to reach my goal?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that this code only close my application and not shut down the device.

You could add debug point in above line, it will throw exception(Access is denied. (`Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 E_ACCESSDENIED`) and make your app crash, it looks shut down the app. In fact the app crashed.

[`BeginShutdown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.shutdownmanager.beginshutdown?view=winrt-19041) method only applicable to IOT device, such as raspberry pie with iot specific OS. And it will not work for Windows 10 Pro tablet, if you do want to  shut down device, we suggest you use desktop bridge to make desktop extension for uwp app and shut down computer with Win32 api `Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /f /t 0");`.